# Why does Selenium Web Driver say Service Unavailable?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

When I run the code below:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
b.goto 'http://www.google.com'
puts b.title
b.close
```

the following error is displayed:

```
/home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:66:in `create_response': unexpected response, code=503, content-type="text/html" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
<HTML><TITLE>503 Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<H1>503 Service Unavailable</H1>
Failed to connect to server <B>127.0.0.1</B></HTML>
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `create_session'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/bridge.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:45:in `new'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:45:in `for'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from /home/jotsarup/.gem/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from test_phantom.rb:7:in `new'
    from test_phantom.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

phantomjs is not connected. I also tried Firefox and the results are the same.

Comment: Are you sitting behind proxy? I have seen similar kind of error when I was using watir-webdriver behind company proxy. I solved it by adding Environment Variable for the proxy.

Comment: Try this:  `b.goto 'https://www.google.com'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are failing to reach outside of your local machine based on "Failed to connect to server **127.0.0.1**" 127.0.0.1 is your loopback address (for your machine) and I have seen this issue arise in the past when there is a firewall up. If you are in a company that requires traffic to be routed through the firewall I would recommend seeing if they see any traffic trying to make it out from your machine. If you're not in a company requiring a firewall then I would recommend dropping the firewall/proxy for testing.

Comment: Got the solution.

export no_proxy = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are behind the `PROXY`. Add the following snippet before starting the server:

```
ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] = ENV['http_proxy'] = nil
b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
```